# Where to find the Workspace ID on watson console?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using the Watson Assistant AI system, and needed to find the Workspace ID code. All websites say go to the skills > three buttons > View API details > Workspace ID, but when I press the View API Details, it only shows the Skills ID and other factors.

Where can I find the Workspace ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information shown for **View API Details** has a section labeled **Legacy v1 Workspace URL**. Part of that URL is the workspace ID, right in front of the `/messages` part.

Watson Assistant [changed the way the information is displayed](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-release-notes#release-notes), but the workspace ID is still present.

Note that it is only needed for the old V1 API.